# Set Background Color on UIButton when Disabled?

Tags: ios, colors, uibutton

Is it possible to set the background color of a *disabled* `UIButton`?  We'd like to use a more muted color when the button is disabled, but I do not see any methods within `UIButton` that would allow this.  Is there a workaround or another way we could accomplish this?

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6309314/986169

Comment: If you're willing to subclass the button, you could just override `-setEnabled:`

Comment: Can please tell the step by which you want to change background color.

Answer (score 10):

I am concentrating on this comment of your's -"We'd like to use a more muted color when the button is disabled". If changing the alpha of the button is an acceptable solution you can very well use this code.

```
someButton.alpha  = 0.5;//This code should be written in the place where the button is disabled.
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way to work with button, in my honest opinion, is subclassing and customize UI, like in example:

```
class XYButton: UIButton {

    override public var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isEnabled {
                self.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(1.0)
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can use `XYButton` either in your storyboards/xibs or programmatically.

** more elegant:

```
didSet {
    self.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(isEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.5)
}
```

Comment: interesting that this not gonna work, if isEnabled set from .xib

Answer (score 5):

Seems that this is not possible as the background color property is controlled by the `UIView` class which is the parent of `UIButton`.

So `UIButton` control state doesn't own this property and doesn't control it.

But still you can inherit `UIButton` and overwrite the `setEnabled` method to update the color accordingly.

This is the most clear way to do it. as you can assign the inherited class to any `UIButton` in storyboard or Xib file. without the need for any connections. (no `IBOutlets`)

Hope this is helpful, if you wish I can share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 35)];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[btn setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: why this code when user can set background color by setBackground method.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya because you can't use setBackgroundColor for specific states.

Comment: In this case you have an issue with setting corner radious

Answer (score 1):

This code is for Swift 2

```
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, someButton.frame.width,someButton.frame.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents(UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor))
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, true, 0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    someButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Disabled)

    someButton.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725169/1586606 
 Set alpha property like;

```
myButton.alpha = 0.5
```