# Storyboard UIButton extension for willSet of isEnabled doesn't get called

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I am trying to make a `UIButton` extension that prints something when setting the `isEnabled` value. But it doesn't seem to be triggered. (Doesn't print):

```
extension UIButton {
    override open var isEnabled: Bool {
        willSet {
            print("About to set isEnabled to \(newValue)")
            // print isn't triggered when I set isEnabled later
        }
    }
}
```

But it works when I use the extension on a custom subclass of `UIButton`:

```
class CustomUIButton: UIButton {}

extension CustomUIButton {
    override open var isEnabled: Bool {
        willSet {
            print("About to set isEnabled to \(newValue)")
            // print is triggered when I set isEnabled later
        }
    }
}
```

The UIButtons are added in the storyboard when it doesn't work but if they are added in code then it works as expected.
Why is this? And how can I make it work on `UIButton`s added in storyboard?

Comment: saw how to do this on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715092/disabled-uibutton-not-faded-or-grey

Comment: I just added your extension... added a `UIButton`... in `viewDidLoad()` called `myButton.isEnabled = false` ... and I see *About to set isEnabled to false* in the debug console.

Comment: Hmm probably it is because I use the storyboard... I edited the question.

Comment: For now I am just using the subclass implementation and setting the UIButton's class in storyboard.

Comment: Curious... works fine in `iOS 12` -- doesn't work in `iOS 13`. Note: same behavior with trying to override `isHighlighted`

Comment: You cant override methods or properties, this guy explains why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to,they%20cannot%20override%20existing%20functionality.&text=The%20compiler%20is%20allowing%20you,for%20compatibility%20with%20Objective%2DC.

Comment: @PRE Why would it work when making a subclass and also in `IOS 12` then? This counts as adding new functionality.

Comment: it also depends on how the button is initialised, if the property is set in init methods, the willSet/didSet method will be not called